# library zxing-js bug to read barcode for 1 month on Android

Tags: javascript, android, zxing

We use the zxing-js library to read barcodes from [our website](https://www.aquariophilie.org/produits/).
It is convenient because the user does not need to download an app.

We are using the latest [version 0.20.0 of Zxing](https://github.com/zxing-js/library).

For more than 1 month we have noticed a bug since reading EANs on Chrome for Android (v. 115.0.5790.138):
A green square is displayed instead of seeing the camera (yet we can hear the noise of the smartphone lens activating)

While on the same smartphone, with Sansung's Internet app (v. 22.0.1.1), barcode reading still works very well!

An idea of ​​the problem ?

I checked, there is no update of the library.
Google Chrome has permission to activate the smartphone camera.
I noticed that the problem is the same on other site which uses the same library.

Comment: Hello, I found the solution on bugs.chromium.org
It's a Chrome browser bug! To solve it, you have to go to the chrome://flags page and disable "Use passthrough command decoder".